# Firebase .then with .on('value')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get `.then()` to work with `.on()` but it only works with `.once()`.

I get `playersRef.on(...).then is not a function`, when trying it with `on()`

So what I have now is this:

```
   let nodesRef = Firebase.database().ref('players')
   let answers = {}
   playersRef.on('value', (playersSnapshot) => {
      playersRef.once('value').then((playersSnapshot) => {
        playersSnapshot.forEach((playerSnapshot) => {
          let playerKey = playerSnapshot.key
          let answersRef = playerSnapshot.child('answers')
          if (answersRef .exists()){
            answers[playerKey ] = answersRef .val()
          }
        })
      }).then(() => {
        console.info(answers);
        dispatch(setPlayerAnswers(answers))
      })
    })
```

But I don't like the fact that it is querying the ref twice.

How would I go about getting `each` player's answer in this example? What would be a more **correct** way? Because I don't think this is the way the Firebase devs intended this.

And what is the reasoning that it is not implemented for `.on()`? Because `playersSnapshot.forEach(...).then` is also not a function... How do I execute something **only once** whenever the `.on('value')` triggers?

Answer (score 11):

*firebaser here*

I'm not entire certain of parts of your question, so will only answer the parts that I can.

> what is the reasoning that [`then()`] is not implemented for `.on()`?

We implemented support for Promises in the Firebase JavaScript clients. The definition of a promise is that it resolves (or fails) only once. Since the Firebase `on()` methods can receive updated data multiple times, it does not fit in the definition of a promise.

> How do I execute something only once whenever the `.on('value')` triggers?

When you want to respond only once to an event, you should use the `once()` method.

I'm not sure why you're having problems with `forEach()`. The following should work:

```
playersRef.on('value', (playersSnapshot) => {
   playersSnapshot.forEach((playerSnapshot) => {
      let playerKey = playerSnapshot.key
      let answersRef = playerSnapshot.child('answers')
      if (answersRef .exists()){
        answers[playerKey ] = answersRef .val()
      }
   })
})
```

If you're having trouble making this work, can you reproduce that problem in a jsbin?

Comment: When I try `.then` after `forEach` I get the error: `layersSnapshot.forEach(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, that's because you handle the `then()` twice: once on line 4 of the snippet and then again on line 12. Promises are chainable, but only if you return another promise from the first `then()` handler.