# Firebase error when subscribing to ref.on(‘value’, callback); | Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database in angular. I am trying to get some data from firebase server in realtime: (Code from a service)

```
getData(child){
        return firebase.database().ref(child).on('value', (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
        })
    }
```

and subscribing to above function in my component:

```
this.examinerService.getData('batches/names').subscribe(
      (batches) => {
        this.batches = batches.val();
      }
    )
```

Which is giving me error:

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any'
```

I have tried using `ref().once()` which works fine but I want realtime behavior.

Update:
Currently I am using `database().ref().on('value', (snapshots) => { console.log(snapshots.val()); });` in my component which works fine but I want to do it inside my service and subscribe to it in my components. Someone told me that its not an observable so you can't subscribe to it. I am new to angular so I don't know how to make an observable and bind snapshots with it.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the FirebaseObjectObservable or FirebaseListObservable classes for this?

Comment: @Woot Sorry, I don't know about these.

Comment: @RobertWillams if you're data structure is something like /batches/names and names is a list of objects you could configure your component like found here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md and just use db.lists('/batches/names') the result would be the list of names.  This is good because the angularfire library either uses polling or websockets I'm not sure which, but it keeps the data up to date realtime. If you would like me to submit an answer with the code details let me know

Comment: @Woot Yeah, Please add that as well :) I am new to firebase and its documentation is pretty confusing for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `getData` is returning the passed callback instead of an `Observable` which is what the code seems to be expecting. You can modify the function as such in order to return an `Observable` that you can `.subscribe()` to.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

getData(child) {

  return Observable.create(subscriber => {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref(child);

    const callbackFn = ref.on('value',
      // emit a value from the Observable when firebase data changes
      (snapshot) => subscriber.next(snapshot.val()),

      // error out the Observable if there is an error
      // such as permission denied
      error => subscriber.error(error)
    );

    // The function passed to Observable.create can return a callback function
    // which will be called when the observable we created is unsubscribed from.
    // Just as we used `ref.on()` previously our callback function calls `ref.off`
    // to tell firebase that we are no longer interested in the changes
    return () => ref.off('value', callbackFn);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect. But couldn't understand some of your code specially the unsubscribe part `return () => ref.off('value', callbackFn);` can you please update  your answer and explain how it is working :)

Comment: I have imported `Subscription` from `rxjs/Subscription` and unsubscribed in `ngOndestroy`. The only thing i am requesting here is I am unable to understand how your code is working. like you have used return two times in the function.

Comment: I have added additional comments to the code. The first return is the return of the created observable. The inner return is used by `Observable.create`. It calls the returned function when the observable has been unsubscribed from.

Comment: Now makes sense to me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say our data structure looks something like this

```
{
  batches: {
    names: [
      {
        first: 'FirstName',
        last: 'LastName'
      },
      {
        first: 'FirstName1',
        last: 'LastName1'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For name we might have an interface that looks like this

```
export interface Name { first: string; last: string; }
```

Then we have a service that looks something like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Name } from "./name";
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2";


@Injectable()
export class NameService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getAllNames(): AngularFireList<Name> {
      return this.db.list('batch/name');
  }

}
```

Last our component can look something like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireList } from "angularfire2";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-list',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let name of names$">
    {{ name.last }}, {{ name.first }}
  </div>
`
})

export class NameListComponent implements OnInit {
  names$: AngularFireList<Name>;

  constructor(private nameService: NameService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.names$ = nameService.getAllNames();
  }
}
```

Angular uses websockets to update in realtime.  I am not sure but I think this might be the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: One point of note is this is using the latest firebase library for Angular 5

Comment: thank you for this. I will try this and contact you if faced any issues :)

Answer (score -2):

`.subscribe()` wont work because the return type is not an `Observable`. You get the `DataSnapshot` in a callback function. Try

```
getData(child){
    return firebase.database().ref(child);
}
```

and in your component

```
this.examinerService.getData('batches/names').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
```

Comment: It gives error in service, "Expected 2-4 arguments but you got 1".

Comment: on() takes 2 or more arguments. So, `on('value', (snapshot)=>{...})` is necessary.

Comment: check this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html), they have done it with one arg.

Comment: my bad, that is `once` method. `.then()` don't work with `.on()` because this methods can receive updated data multiple times. check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402110/firebase-then-with-onvalue)

Comment: btw you can call the `.on()` from component

Comment: I know about once() but I want realtime behavior. I dont want to use it in component, because all of my firebase functions are in a service so why only this should be in component? Doesn't feel good.