# Listening firebase changes from components with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want to access some data inside multiple components. I created a service, which retrieves data for this purpose. Problem appears, when I try to observe my data. My code:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {

    constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) {}

    public retrieveNotifications(): Observable<NotificationObj[]> {
      return this.af.database.ref(refs.NOTIFICATIONS).on('value', snap => {
        const data = snap.val();
        return Object.keys(data).map(key => {
          return new NotificationObj(key, data[key]);
        });
      })
    }
}
```

I get the message:

> TS2322: Type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any' is not assignable to type 'Observable<NotificationObj[]>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any'.

How can I transform my method to avoid parsing data outside the service and save possibility to listen changes from components?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution there [Firebase error when subscribing to ref.on(‘value’, callback); | Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629828/firebase-error-when-subscribing-to-ref-on-value-callback-property-subscr/48713076)

Comlete code is:

```
  public retrieveNotifications(): Observable<NotificationObj[]> {
    return Observable.create(subscriber => {
      const ref = this.af.database.ref(refs.NOTIFICATIONS);
      const callback = ref.on('value', snap => {
        const data = snap.val();
        const notifications = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
          return new NotificationObj(key, data[key]);
        });
        subscriber.next(notifications);
      });
      return () => ref.off('value', callback);
    })
  }
```